Error: an Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 ('PARM') (illustrator v2024)
I have been getting these errors very often in almost my simplest scripts for a long time. I am getting this warning even though I have tried all the alternatives thinking it may be in the coordinate system. When I researched, there are people who get similar errors but no definitive solution has been provided.
//this script task: Adds the selected objects to the page in cm.
// The error it gives every now and then is:
// Error: an Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 ('PARM')
#target illustrator
offsetT=0 
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
myDoc.rulerOrigin = [0,0];
var sel = app.selection; //sel as selections array.
var str = "";
function essenziki() {
    if(sel.length==0){
        alert("choose something first");
        return
     }

for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) { //loop and check each selected objects
  str += (pt2mm(sel[i].width) / 10+offsetT).toFixed(0) + "*" + (pt2mm(sel[i].height) / 10+offsetT).toFixed(0)+ "\n";
}
str = str.replace(/\n$/, ''); // Replace last line break to empty symbol
var tx = myDoc.textFrames.add();
    tx.contents = str;
tx.textRange.characterAttributes.size=150; 
tx.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = app.textFonts.getByName('Arial-BoldMT');

app.executeMenuCommand("deselectall"); //deselect all abjects

var cmykColor = new CMYKColor();
cmykColor.cyan = 34;
cmykColor.magenta = 49;
cmykColor.yellow = 19;
cmykColor.black = 27;
tx.textRange.characterAttributes.fillColor = cmykColor; 

app.executeMenuCommand("deselectall"); //deselect all abjects
    tx.selected = true; 

function pt2mm(n){
  return n * 0.35277778;
}

};
essenziki();

if (app.selection.length > 0) {
    var selectedItem = app.selection[0]; // Get the first selected item

    // Get the center of the current view in document coordinates
    var viewCenter = app.activeDocument.activeView.centerPoint; // [x, y] of view center in document coordinates

    // Calculate the center of the selected item
    var itemBounds = selectedItem.geometricBounds; // [left, top, right, bottom]
    var itemCenterX = (itemBounds[0] + itemBounds[2]) / 2;
    var itemCenterY = (itemBounds[1] + itemBounds[3]) / 2;

    // Calculate the offset to move the item to the center of the view
    var offsetX = viewCenter[0] - itemCenterX;
    var offsetY = viewCenter[1] - itemCenterY;

    // Move the item to the center of the view
    selectedItem.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
}


Sorry can't reproduce the error. The code works fine for me. The 'PARM' error usually means something outside the Illustrator perse. I'd try to exclude the app.executeMenuCommand() from the code. It can work without them.

Just in case, here is the variant of the code without app.executeMenuCommand() (probably the error has something do to with this method). Try it:
function main() {
    app.activeDocument.rulerOrigin = [0,0];
    var offsetT = 0;
    var str = [];
    var w, h;
    var cm = 0.035277778;

    for (var i = 0; i < app.selection.length; i++) {
        w = (app.selection[i].width  * cm + offsetT).toFixed(0);
        h = (app.selection[i].height * cm + offsetT).toFixed(0);
        str.push( w + "*" + h);
    }

    var tx = app.activeDocument.textFrames.add();
    tx.contents = str.join("\n");
    tx.textRange.characterAttributes.size = 150;
    tx.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = app.textFonts.getByName("Arial-BoldMT");

    var cmykColor = new CMYKColor();
    cmykColor.cyan    = 34;
    cmykColor.magenta = 49;
    cmykColor.yellow  = 19;
    cmykColor.black   = 27;
    tx.textRange.characterAttributes.fillColor = cmykColor;

    var viewCenter = app.activeDocument.activeView.centerPoint;
    var itemBounds = tx.geometricBounds;
    var itemCenterX = (itemBounds[0] + itemBounds[2]) / 2;
    var itemCenterY = (itemBounds[1] + itemBounds[3]) / 2;
    var offsetX = viewCenter[0] - itemCenterX;
    var offsetY = viewCenter[1] - itemCenterY;
    tx.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
};

if (app.selection.length > 0) main();
else alert("Choose something first.");

It doesn't select or deselect anything, but does it even need to?

ERROR Error in
Line 26: tx.textRange.characterAttributes.size = 150;
an Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 (‘PARM'] error It starts doing it again from time to time. Not all the time. So it seems to be not working stable. Could the Win 10 system be causing this? I'm not sure, of course, it's a conspiracy theory.

Weird, indeed. Perhaps the way WIn10 handles fonts causes the error. As a work around you can try don't change the font attributes. Left the default font. And resize the text frame with tx.resize(1250,1250) method.

After a long testing process, it was working fine until now. Until
ERROR Error in
tx.textRange.characterAttributes.fillColor = cmykColor;
an Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 ('PARM')
I was just adding the following code to the end of the code and testing it.
Because I can't see that it randomly throws it to the page. I had to select something. These errors are either I shouldn't select something or I shouldn't give it a color. I'm confused.
if (app.selection.length > 0) {     app.selection = null;     tx.selected = true;   }
